# extracting multiple columns from multiple files and merge them to a single table

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have nearly 500 files each with more that 120 columns and some of the columns are blank.

```
hghflf.maf
lnuegflkn.maf
jdfrlbvfl11.maf
jkfbrhw4rkb4.maf
....
```

here is an example of the head of data for the first couple of columns (in total 148 columns):

```
  Hugo_Symbol Entrez_Gene_Id Center NCBI_Build Chromosome Start_Position
1     Unknown              0      .     GRCh38       chr2        4871838
2    RNU5E-7P              0      .     GRCh38       chr2       15866667
3      CAPN13              0      .     GRCh38       chr2       30736899
4     Unknown              0      .     GRCh38       chr2       35346478
```

I want to extract only columns 1,4,5 and make a last column which is (column43+column41/column43)(these columns are not shown in the example) for each file (so 4 columns in total) and merge these for all files to a single table.Any idea how to do it?

---

[editor] Parsed by `column -t` for readability:

```
Hugo_Symbol  Entrez_Gene_Id  Center  NCBI_Build  Tumor_Sample_Barcode  Chromosome  Start_Position  Reference_Allele  Tumor_Seq_Allele2  Reference_Allele
Unknown      0               .       GRCh37      10-26934N             2           181552          T                 C                  T
Unknown      0               .       GRCh37      10-26934N             2           2742215         G                 A                  G
PQLC3        0               .       GRCh37      10-26934N             2           11291948        C                 T                  C
MIR3681HG    0               .       GRCh37      10-26934N             2           12522789        C                 A                  C
AC010880.1   0               .       GRCh37      10-26934N             2           16536811        C                 G                  C
Unknown      0               .       GRCh37      10-26934N             2           17111275        A                 C                  A
Unknown      0               .       GRCh37      10-26934N             2           19044748        A                 -                  A
Unknown      0               .       GRCh37      10-26934N             2           19114714        A                 G                  A
AC018742.1   0               .       GRCh37      10-26934N             2           21935272        T                 C                  T
```

Comment: I understand that the first three columns of your desired output are input columns 1, 4 and 5. I don't understand what the fourth column is supposed to be. Why don't you add an example of an output line to your question? By the way, the list of filenames at the beginning of your question is not useful. I would remove it so that readers get to the point immediately.

Comment: If you say "some of the columns are blank", are they blank in _all_ input files or just in some? Are they blank in _all lines_, or just in some? How are they separated? Tabs, whitespace, ... ? What would the desired output look like? Do you want to include a header line?

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{ print $1, $4, $5, "Median" }
     FNR>1{ print $1, $4, $5, ($41+$43)/$43 }' ./multiple-files* >single-table-output
```